# Facebook Group API stop working after April 4, 2018

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Here is a quote from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

> Beginning April 4, 2018, all apps, including those formerly approved,
>   must undergo App Review in order to gain access to the Events API,
>   Groups API, and Pages API. Apps accessing the Events API and Groups
>   API will lose access and require review once App Review resumes. For
>   apps using Pages API, review will be required once App Review resumes
>   or access will be removed.

My app uses a Group API to fetch posts from the several groups and display it more convenient way. Now, to get it back I need to pass a Review which is forcing me to ask what permissions I  want to use and show how (make a screencast)

Issues:

1. I don't need any permissions from the user.
2. The app is under the developing so I actually need to get an access to the API to create an APP and then show to a reviewer how to use it.
3. Here is API changes: `Going forward, all apps will require explicit admin authorization.` How exactly admin suppose to authorize it?

Any clarifications, discussions and tips are welcomed.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes

Comment: @luschn list item number 3 has a quote from this post. I have not found an answer here to my questions. As far as i can tell only admin can access to the /feeds but anyone else can get info of this group without admin authorization, whatever it is.

Comment: right now, you cannot get access at all, because review is closed for now. you can only wait.

Comment: Surprisingly I can access /{{groupID}}/feed by GET request or by javascript SDK. But I can't do the same with graph explorer.

Comment: We are in the same boat. Cant do me/groups. Stopped working yesterday. Have to wait for new review process to open up.

Comment: The similar behaviour here. When I try to get feed using graph explorer it returns 
"Unsupported get request. Object with ID '2004xxxxxxxxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation

Comment: We are having the same problem